# Why would Browsersync live reload for one compilation task but not another?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, browser-sync

I have a gulpfile running to compile Sass, CoffeeScript, and live reload both through Browsersync:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
      style: 'expanded',
      precision: 10
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions',   'Firefox ESR']}))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


gulp.task('coffee', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/coffee/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'http://mamp-site.dev'
  });
  gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./src/coffee/**/*.coffee', ['coffee']);
});
```

Browsersync successfully reloads my compiled JS every time I make a change, but won't reload my compiled CSS. I know placing `browserSync.stream()` after `gulp.dest()` is correct, because Browsersync says it [only cares about your CSS when it's finished compiling](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-sass-css). I also verified that my Sass is compiling.

Why would Browsersync work for my `'coffee'` task but not my `'sass'` task? This is my first go at gulp, so I'm hoping it's something simple.

**EDIT:** watching `'sass'` only within the `'serve'` task works, but not with both `'sass'` and `'coffee'`

Comment: IMHO: You should try webpack and leave the gulp..

Comment: @Hardy, isn't webpack overkill for something like this? I've only done minimal research on it. And what makes webpack (or any other module bundler) better than a task runner like gulp, or even grunt?

Comment: @Hardy, FWIW I'm using this on a Drupal theme

Comment: I don't think webpack is "overkill" for this kind of stuff. Gulp is always better than grunt because gulp is all about streams and building complex pipelines. It uses node.js’ streams, and executes faster, since it does not open/close files, or create intermediary copies all the time like grunt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your sass is not reloading, but you should not be using browserSync.stream for your javascript. Perhaps the streams are getting mixed up. Your watch should be

```
gulp.watch('./src/coffee/**/*.coffee', ['coffee-watch']);
```

and there should be

```
gulp.task('coffee-watch', ['coffee'], function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});
```

Remove `.pipe(browserSync.stream());` from your coffee task.

Comment: thank you, but can you explain why this is better? If `browserSync.stream()` is wrong, why does Browsersync recommend it? https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-sass-css. Stream is used to inject the changes, if there's a Browsersync instance running. And your `done()` function implies Browsersync is running asynchronously, but doesn't it run in sync with the gulp pipe?

Comment: Hi - stream is correct for css changes, but not for js/coffee changes. js changes require a full page reload (refresh), which is done by browserSync.reload. css changes can just be injected into your page without doing a full page refresh, and the way you have done that is correct.  The browserSync docs show both methods, one for sass and one for js. https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-reload

Comment: Ah, reloading the whole window with JS changes sounds so obvious now. I also just noticed your answer is what Browsersync recommends below the CSS injection section: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-reload. So I tried your solution, and both `'sass'` and `'coffee'` reload correctly! Thank you